# How does the Promise.coroutine support generator as the yieldable value?

Tags: node.js, promise, coroutine, bluebird

`Promise.coroutine` supports `Promise` as the yieldable value type. And via the `addYieldHandler(function handler)`, `Promise.coroutine` can also support any types that retuning result only once. But how could I write a yieldHandler that can handle a `generator` type like [co](https://github.com/visionmedia/co) does?

Answer (score 26):

First of all, Bluebird coroutines return promises that are of course yieldable on their own:

```
var foo = Promise.coroutine(function*(){
    yield Promise.delay(3000);
});

var bar = Promise.coroutine(function*(){
    yield foo(); // you can do this.
});
```

Generally, a generator is syntactic sugar for a function that returns an iterable sequence. There is nothing asynchronous about it in nature. You can write code that returns iterables in ES5 and even ES3 and consume it with `yield` in a generator.

Now - as for your question:

#### I would not recommend using `Promise.coroutine` like that.

Yielding arbitrary iterables from the specific iterable you're using is error prone, where wrapping it in `Promise.coroutine` makes it an explicit coroutine which you can easily yield. This is explicit, clear, and preserves all sorts of useful properties.

Yielding promises is not coincidental, and there is a good reason that `async` functions in ES7 await promises. Promises represent a temporal value and they're really the only thing waiting for makes sense - they represent exactly that - something you wait for. For that reason - explicitly waiting for promises is beneficial and makes for a solid abstraction.

#### If you do want to yield from an arbitrary generator - you don't need to add a yield handler via Bluebird.

Generators in JavaScript already have that ability built in using special notation, there is no need to add a specific exception to a specific promise library in order to yield from other iterables.

```
function genThreeToFour*(){
    yield 3;
    yield 4;
}
function genOneToFive*(){
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield * genThreeToFour(); // note the *, delegate to another sequence
    yield 5;
}
```

Yielding from another sequence is already built into generators, if you want to yield from another generator you can simply `yield *` invoking it. That way it's explicit you're delegating. It's only one more character of code but it's a lot more explicit and it's also easier to step through with debuggers since the engine is aware of delegation. I still prefer yielding promises only but if you feel strongly about this - delegating to other generators sounds a lot better than yielding generators explicitly.

Note that this is also much faster than yielding generators explicitly since the conversion process of `Promise.coroutine` isn't cheap since it's meant to be executed once and then used so the conversion itself isn't fast but it produces a very fast function (faster than `async` in almost all use cases, and faster than how most people write callacks in most use cases. If you delegate instead of creating a coroutine every time and running it - you'll have better performance.

#### If you insist, you can `addYieldHandler`

It's quite possible to do this. If you're ok with the speed penalty and the (in my opinion worse) abstraction. You can use `addYieldHandler` to make it possible to yield generators.

First, the "good" way:

```
Promise.coroutine.addYieldHandler(function(gen) {
    if (gen && gen.next && gen.next.call ){ // has a next which is a function
        return Promise.try(function cont(a){
            var n = gen.next(a);
            if(n.done) return n.value; // `return` in generator
            if(!n.value.then) return cont(n.value); // yield plain value
            // handle promise case, propagate errors, and continue
            return n.value.catch(gen.throw.bind(gen)).then(cont); 
        });
    }
});
```

Here - we added the ability to yield *iterables* and not generators, the advantage is that functions that are not generators (for example - from third party libraries) but still produce iterables can still be yielded. The usage of the above is something along the lines of: `yield generatorFn()` where you invoke the generator. Note that our code here replicates what `Promise.coroutine` actually does and we almost ended up with a "native" implementation of it.

Now, if you want to yield *generators*, you can still do that:

```
var Gen = (function*(){}).constructor;
Promise.coroutine.addYieldHandler(function(gen) {
    if (gen && (gen instanceof Gen)){ // detect explicit generator
        return Promise.coroutine(gen)();
    }
});
```

That's for the sake of completeness though :)